# UITableView inside UITableViewCell not resizing the cell height

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have created a tableView which has two cells: the first one is just a tableViewCell with some labels and is the one you see at the top; the second cell is an embedded table view.

The issue I am having is that the cell that has the embedded table view is not resizing according to the embedded table view size. In this screenshot, the embedded table view is in green and red are the cells of that embedded table view. There are some red cells hidden because the cell did not expand as expected.

[image]

The cell that has the embedded table view is defined here:
[image]

The cell of the embedded table view is this:

[image]

Comment: This is - generally - a bad design. You'd be much better off using either two cell types / classes, or using multiple sections in your table view.

Comment: Why is it a bad design? I do have two cell types. Each cell has its own view, defined in a XIB, and a corresponding class that hosts the view's view model. So, the first cell acts like a section header and the second cell acts as a section body. Neither cell is a section header as defined by UITableView. Not sure how using/not using section headers would solve the issue....any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, embedding a table view in a table view cell is a bad design for a number of reasons.

- Table views do not have an intrinsic Height... so no matter how many cells you add, it won't set its own height. There are ways around that, but...
- Changing the height of a table view based on the number of cells defeats the "reusable" cell design. Table views use that for memory management.
- You end up with scrolling in the content of a cell, while the table view holding that cell also wants to scroll.
- You need a separate `dataSource` and `delegate` class for each table view.

Unless you have a ***much*** more complex design than you've shown, or you have some other compelling reason to embed a table view in a cell, you're much better off with this approach:

- One table view
- Two cell classes - I'll call them White and Red to match your image
- One `dataSource` - returns a `WhiteCell` if `indexPath.row == 0` and returns a `RedCell` for the rest of the rows.

Here's an outline of that approach:

```
class WhiteCell: UITableViewCell {
    func configureCell(_ strings: [String]) -> Void {
        // configure the labels for this cell
    }
}
class RedCell: UITableViewCell {
    func configureCell(_ strings: [String]) -> Void {
        // configure the labels for this cell
    }
}

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    let whiteData: [String] = [
        "Line 1",
        "Line 2",
        "Line 3",
        "Line 4",
        // etc...
    ]
    
    let redData: [[String]] = [
        [ "A string 1", "A string 2", "A string 3", ],
        [ "B string 1", "B string 2", "B string 3", ],
        [ "C string 1", "C string 2", "C string 3", ],
        [ "D string 1", "D string 2", "D string 3", ],
        // etc...
    ]

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // number of red rows + the white row
        return redData.count + 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WhiteCell", for: indexPath) as! WhiteCell
            cell.configureCell(whiteData)
            return cell
        }
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RedCell", for: indexPath) as! RedCell
        // because the red cells start at .row == 1, and the data array is zero-based,
        //  we use [indexPath.row - 1]
        cell.configureCell(redData[indexPath.row - 1])
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

Comment: thank you. For those in this question, the answer to why the inner table view is not resizing, it's because it does not have an intrinsic size. 

@DonMag, the reason I chose this approach is because there is some styling that connects all the rows of the inner table view, and putting them in their own view, makes that easier at the expense of other things. I'll see if I can get around the self-inflicted autoresizing issue.

Comment: @anr - when posting a question here, it's a good idea to fully explain what you're trying to do. That helps avoid situations like this.

Comment: understand. Not always can one share the details. Nonetheless, you covered all.